# Comparing different types of C++ for-loops

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, iterator

C++ is very flexible, and I want to understand for-loop operations more deeply. I'm hoping for a good comparison of each implementation and what is better/faster/more efficient. Additionally, it would be a perk to learn some other way of implementing a for-loop - and not necessarily something in the STL.

I'm looking for expert answers, not opinions. Notice the many limitations I've put on answers: answers pertain only to the specific for-loops mentioned, their limitations (which may not be intuitive), specific alternatives not in the STL, and specific enhancements.

How do these other for-loops (not the 'traditional') work differently/better?

What are the limitations of the other 'non-traditional' for-loops?

Example 1) Traditional for-loop is:

```
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
    //do something for each iteration;
}
```

Example 2) Now lets say I have a vector of scores.

```
vector<int> scores = {77,91,100,88,85,68,95};

for (auto it = scores.begin(); it != scores.end(); ++it){
    //do something for each iteration;
}
```

Example 3) Same scores vector, different loop.

```
for (auto& x: scores) //do something for each iteration;
```

I'm particularly interested in example 3, because it is so simple, I'm not sure what it's actually doing, yet functionally is the same as the other two.

Comment: All of your samples are orthogonal to each other, and it heavily depends on `//do something for each iteration` how these would be comparable at a semantical level.

Comment: Also asking for _"pros and cons"_ almost always ends up to get questions closed as _primarily opinion based_ or _too broad_.

Comment: Example 1 is buggy.   The loop variable should be vector<int>::size_type not int (and int overflow has undefined behaviour).

Comment: @JamesYoungman it's not buggy if that particular vector's size is guaranteed to be less than or equal to `INT_MAX`. Very often you have such guarantee and using `int` as loop counter is very common. But for cases when a massive vector is a possibility, you're correct.

Comment: If by orthogonal it is meant the three for-loop examples are statically discreet, meaning they have totally different behavior, all the more reason to understand them. If meaning they have no difference, or 'zero-sum', then that is incorrect, because adding iterators adds a certain amount of overhead. 

I've not encountered a conversation where asking for pro/cons invited wild opinions. It opens the floor to reviewing specific strengths/weaknesses. Given the audience here is stackoverflow, I expected I wouldn't have to state this directly, because I didn't ask on Facebook, and it is implicit.

Comment: `for (auto i : c) {/*code*/};` is just the same as `for (decltype(c)::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it) { auto i = *it; /*code*/ };`

Comment: And yet, if the limitations are different, as illustrated in the answer, doesn't that make them different?

Comment: @user2079303 that statement is strictly true, but I don't think it's a helpful way to think about this.  The constraint (foo.size() < INT_MAX) may hold at the time you write the code but how would you preserve that invariant throughout the lifetime of the code?   An assertion won't  fire in production (_NDEBUG) code. Better to develop good habits (in this case ensuring that you use consistent types on both sides of the ````==```` test) so that you don't end up with an indefinite number of code features waiting for a change in the way they're used to turn them into bugs.

Comment: @JamesYoungman I agree, it's a good practice to use the container's size type for iteration. My point was just that calling the example code *buggy* is too strong claim. Without knowing anything about the context, it's impossible to tell whether the invariant is easy to preserve. Perhaps they are iterating over a list of parents of a person. I would feel safe enough to assume the invariant of `parents_of_p < 32767` to hold and wouldn't worry about overflowing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You have access to `i` that you can use to figure out whether you're in the first, last or some other iteration. Not usable with non-random-access containers, so not an option for generic code that must work with vectors and lists alike. Supported since the first version of c++ standard.
2. Works with all standard iterators and therefore appropriate for generic code. No access to iteration counter, but the count can be calculated with `std::distance`, however, if the iterator is not random access, then that adds up the complexity of iteration. Figuring out if you are in first or last iteration is still constant time, though. Supported since the first version of c++ standard.
3. Much nicer syntax, but semantically equivalent to certain forms of 2. Sub-ranges can not be used: goes always from begin to end<sup>†</sup> (unless you break out). No way to access iteration counter. Did not exist prior to c++11. There also exists macro based implementations such as `BOOST_FOREACH` that do a similar thing and support the older standard.

<sup>†</sup> Iterator ranges can be used with the range-based for loop to get around this. They're not part of the standard library, but there are third party implementations.

---

TL;DR

1. Handy when you need the iterator count and don't need generic code.
2. For generic pre c++11 code.
3. A good choice by default due to its simplicity.

Answer (score 7):

Version 3 is basically a short hand way of saying Version 2.

The item on the right `scores` must support `std::begin(scores)` and `std::end(scores)` and becomes syntactically equivalent too:

```
  for (auto& x: scores)
  {
      // STUFF
  }

  // Is the same as:

  for(auto tmp = std::begin(scores); tmp != std::end(scores); ++tmp)
  {
      auto& x = *tmp;
      // tmp not technically available.
      // STUFF
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal for loop is useful when you don't want to visit every element in the array or if you have more than one loop variable.

```
for (int i = 0, j = 2; i != 10; ++i, ++j) { ... }
```

From [Herb Sutter's](https://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/) blog:

> The range-based for loop is a much more convenient way to visit every
>   element of a range in order.

```
// C++98
for( vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i ) {
    total += *i;
}

// C++11
for( auto d : v ) {
    total += d;
}
```